# Magento 2 Credit Memos : Template override doesn't work after clicking "Update Qty's" button

Tags: magento-2.1, module, template, creditmemo

I am creating a custom module to simplify the Credit Memo creation for admin users. One of the features is hiding the "Return to Stock" column. I have overwritten 2 files for this:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/creditmemo/create/items.phtml

vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/creditmemo/create/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

With the following files of my custom module:

app/code/ATC/CreditMemo/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">ATC_CreditMemo::order/creditmemo/create/items.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="ATC_CreditMemo::order/creditmemo/create/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/ATC/CreditMemo/view/adminhtml/templates/order/creditmemo/create/items.phtml

In this file I simply removed the following code:

```
<?php if ($block->canReturnToStock()) : ?>
<th class="col-return-to-stock"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Return to Stock') ?></span></th>
<?php endif; ?>
```

app/code/ATC/CreditMemo/view/adminhtml/templates/order/creditmemo/create/items/renderer/default.phtml

In this file I simply removed the following code:

```
<?php if ($block->canParentReturnToStock($_item)) : ?>
    <td class="col-return-to-stock">
    <?php if ($block->canReturnItemToStock($_item)) : ?>
        <input type="checkbox"
               class="admin__control-checkbox"
               name="creditmemo[items][<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getOrderItemId() ?>][back_to_stock]"
               value="1"<?php if ($_item->getBackToStock()):?> checked<?php endif;?>/>
        <label class="admin__field-label"></label>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

All of this works fine when creating a new Credit Memo until a user clicks 
the "Update Qty's" button after changing the value of the "Qty to Refund" of any order item. When clicking this button, the following Javascript function is triggered:

```
submitAndReloadArea($('creditmemo_item_container'),'http://store_url.com/admin/sales/order_creditmemo/updateQty/order_id/xxxx/key/yyyy/')
```

The whole "#creditmemo_item_container" HTML area gets reloaded and the "Return to Stock" column reappears. It seems like the template files I have overwritten are still being used when calling that function. How could I fix this so the template files of my custom module are used instead (just like the first time the page is loaded)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to correct:
app/code/ATC/CreditMemo/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml

for proper overwrite renderer/default.phtml so change:

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="ATC_CreditMemo::order/creditmemo/create/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
```

to:

```
<referenceBlock name="order_items.default">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">ATC_CreditMemo::order/creditmemo/create/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
        </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

And the reason why after update qty the block is refreshed, because you miss overwriting sales_order_creditmemo_updateqty.xml

Create app/code/ATC/CreditMemo/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_updateqty.xml

and paste the same content after fix as you have in sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">ATC_CreditMemo::order/creditmemo/create/items.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="order_items.default">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">ATC_CreditMemo::order/creditmemo/create/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```